# How can I use patch as a method call?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, python-unittest

The `unittest` docs state:

> `patch()` acts as a function decorator, class decorator or a context
>   manager

I found the following way to also allow patching via a method call. You can then patch something by calling this method. For example, this is helpful for patching something in a setup method:

```
class MyTestCase(TestCase):

    def patch(self, target, new):
        p = patch(target, new)
        p.start()
        self.addCleanup(p.stop)

    # ...

    def setUp(self):
        self.a = Mock()
        self.patch("whatever.I.want.to.patch", self.a)

    def test(self):
        ...
        self.a.assert_called_once()
```

Is there a cleaner way of doing this? What is the reasoning for not providing this functionality out of the box?

Comment: self refers to the TestCase. In the example above, I am setting a mock as an object attribute then patching something using that. The mock is then available anywhere within the test case/class)

Comment: Oh sorry, yes, my mistake. Edited, thanks for picking that up :)

Comment: I suppose a better title might be *"Why is `patch` not already a method on `TestCase`?"*, as you appear to know the answer to the current title. But realistically that can only be answered by a small number of people (and perhaps only with *"we didn't think of it"*).